# Including Certificates with Project

Tags: .net, deployment, digital-certificate

I have a .NET console application project which consumes a WCF service. In order to consume the service, the application must provide several digital certificates.

Until now, I've been running this application from my local machine, so the application was able to pull in the certificates from my local filesystem. However, I'm currently interested in deploying the app to several other machines.

What is the correct way to include these certificates in the project? In particular, does it make sense to store the certificates in `resource` files?

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting for me; I'll be dealing with the same issue in a few months in my own project.

I would say a big part of the answer will depend on how you plan to *manage* the certificates. Will they need to be updated as part of a regular key rotation (i.e., is this for anything other than a low-risk intranet application)? Since you're already using digital certificates, my guess is the application deals with high-value data and either is not running in an intranet or the service is external to your intranet (otherwise, you ought to be using Windows integrated authentication with a service account) - either way it sounds like you will have to update your certificates regularly (perhaps annually).

So, the key question for you, I think, is: if the certificates have to be updated, will you want to be doing that via a redeployment of the application?

You can certainly include the certificate in a resource file. You could also bundle them in an MSI package that you build with [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) (shout-out to one of the coolest OSS projects I've seen :)). But if you're going to update the certificates outside of the app deployment schedule, none of those approaches make sense.

In that case, you probably want to think about a separate script/mini-installer/service that simply exists to update the certificates. PowerShell might be the simplest way to address this need - especially if the application is running only in your intranet (there are lots of tools available to automate running PowerShell scripts regularly on remote machines).

Yeah, overall I would probably say go with a PowerShell script for the certificate deployment. Then you just need to code your app to be able to handle a change in the certificate (e.g., I don't think you'll be able to rely on the thumbprint for anything like looking up the certificate in a certificate store). If you're just loading the certificate from a file, that's not even an issue.